# How to force a specific URL to tunnel through VPN (OpenVPN)?

Tags: vpn

I currently have a VPN server running and I am attached to it as a client. The current setup is such that *only* routes 10.0.0.0/16 are tunnelled through the VPN. Additionally, I push Amazon's internal DNS server (10.0.0.2) to the client so if I hit any of my private hosted zones then Route 53 will take care of the redirection.

My question is, how can I route a specific URL to tunnel through the VPN? For example:

`google.com -> local wifi`

`abc.com -> vpn`

where `abc.com` is my specified URL that I want to make sure gets tunneled.

Comment: Do you have control over the VPN server?  What kind is it?

Comment: Yes, it is OpenVPN.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4, and questions about host/server configurations, are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have the IP of abc.com included in the tunnel policy.

Comment: My issue is that abc.com maps to multiple, possibly frequently changing IP addresses.

Comment: You have a problem :)  Your VPN client  routes traffic based on network layer information (IP addresses), but you want it to route based on information contained in the http data.  Furthermore, you want to do this based on a DNS query that can resolve to an arbitrary IP address.   I can't think of how this would be possible without writing a custom client.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, and okay fair enough, I will look into possible solutions that can help me out here.

Comment: How about running a script in crontab that updates the IP route table? I have two NICs and I want to route some IPs to a specific connection.